# Uniform Convergence of a series of functions using the Dirichlet's test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

I have recently been trying out some questions on series of functions. I got stuck in one of those problems in which I am supposed to show that the below series of functions is uniformly convergent on any bounded interval.

The series is given by:
$$\sum_{1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$$

I tried using the Dirichlet's test over here by letting $a_n(x)=(-1)^n$ and $b_n(x)=\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$ but what I am unable to prove here is that $b_n(x)$ is monotonic and uniformly converging to $0$ for all $x$ in a bounded interval.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ large enough so that your bounded interval is contained in $[-m,m]$. Then show that $\langle b_n:n>m\rangle$ is monotonic and converges uniformly to $0$ on $[-m,m]$. Dirichlet’s test then allows you to conclude that $$\sum_\limits{n>m}(-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$$ converges, which is good enough. It may be helpful to rewrite $b_n$ as

$$b_n=\left(\frac{x}n\right)^2+\frac1n\;.$$

Comment: How do we show that that it uniformly converges to zero?

Comment: @Shivani: Look at its maximum value on the interval.

Comment: It will be  $\frac{m^2+n}{n^2}$..now what?

Comment: @Shivani: What happens to it as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: It tends to zero..so that sequence on the right uniformly converges to zero?..what can we say about the sequence on the left?

Comment: @Shivani: I’m not sure what you mean by ‘on the right’ and ‘on the left’ here.

Comment: i meant $\frac{m^2+n}{n^2}$ uniformly converges to zero..that's what we get

Comment: @Shivani: I still don’t understand ‘on the left’ and ‘on the right’, I’m afraid.

Comment: from that argument, we get that $\frac{m^2+n}{n^2}$ converges uniformly to zero..not bn(x)..isn't it?..how can we imply that bn(x) uniformly converges to zero?

Comment: @Shivani: $0\le b_n(x)\le\frac{m^2+n}{n^2}$ for all $x\in[-m,m]$.

Comment: Okay..So by squeeze theorem,we have that bn(x) converges to zero..How to show that happens uniformly?

Comment: @Shivani: That’s trivial: if $|b_n(m)|<\epsilon$, then $|b_n(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in[-m,m]$.

Comment: Thank you..I think I got it..Have you taken n>m just to claim that the maximum value of bn(x) tends to zero?

Comment: @Shivani: I realized afterwards that it wasn’t actually necessary; I did it originally just to keep things simple by ensuring that $\left|\frac{x}n\right|<1$ and therefore $b_n(x)<2$, so that I didn’t have to worry about any oddities with small $n$.

Comment: So we get 2 is an upper bound of {b$_n$ for n>m} ?..what could we imply from there?

Comment: Anyway..Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Shivani: The $2$ actually wasn’t important: I was just avoiding potential problems that didn’t actually exist. (That’s a byproduct of experience: make things as simple as possible when you’re still thinking your way through something. In this case it wasn’t necessary.) You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Denote $S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$ and $s_n(x)=(-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$.

You have

$$\left\vert s_{2n}(x) + s_{2n+1}(x) \right\vert = \left\vert \frac{x^2(4n+1) -2n(2n+1)}{(2n)^2(2n+1)^2} \right\vert \le \frac{M^2 + 1}{2n(2n+1)}$$

for $x \in [0,M]$. Therefore, the series converges uniformly on all bounded intervals as $\sum 1/n^2$ is convergent.

**Note: this is not using Dirichlet test but [normal convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_convergence).**

Comment: From this,we get $\sum|s$_2n$(x)-s$_2n+1$(x)|$ converges..Don't we?

Comment: In fact we get that $\sum \vert s_2n(x) + s_{2n+1}(x) \vert$ converges because the $(-1)^n$ is already in the $s_n(x)$.

Comment: What?..I didn't get it

Comment: @Shivani Have you try to write $s_{2n}(x) + s_{2n+1}(x)$ as I did where $s_n(x)=(-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$?

Comment: Is the above series absolutely convergent?

Comment: For sure it is if you look at the bound I provided.

Comment: How did you get the bound?..N also I think there is a calculation mistake